# String object creation using constructor of byte[] and charset

Tags: java, encoding

I am creating a String object using `new String(byte[], Charset)` where `Charset = UTF8` and `byte[]` is encoded into `ISO-8859-1`.
I have tested with normal characters and it worked. But not clear if it can create any problem.

Pleas suggest.

```
new String(byteArray,Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Why don't you use the correct charset instead?

Comment: Sooo, you decode ISO-8859-1 with UTF-8 and been wondering why it shows up malformed? Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you use a key to open a lock it doesn't belong to? That's what you're doing here.

Comment: As i am reading XML which has encoding in UTF-8 and my DB has ISO-8859-1 , so i am removing unmapped and malformed chars and thn resetting data into XML to process , so converting in UTF-8 back.

Answer (score 1):

Read the API documentation regarding the constructor. According to that you will not get any issues even if you get a corrupted byte array.

**public String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)**

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using
>   the specified charset. The length of the new String is a function of
>   the charset, and hence may not be equal to the length of the byte
>   array.
>   **This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement string.** The CharsetDecoder class should be used when more control over
>   the decoding process is required